# Add Class and Perform Animation on Click, Reverse on Click Again

Tags: jquery-animate, toggle, removeclass

I have a wrap element that is hidden initially. Once clicked the hidden element needs to have a visible class added, before performing a toggle animation on another element. Then once clicked again, the animated element needs to toggle it's animation, and then remove said class from the wrap.

Here is what I have thus far. The initial click performs fine. Class is added, and animation is performed. But on click again the animation is performed properly, but once it is completed, the class is not removed.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.search-btn').click(function() {
    if ($('.search-form-wrap').hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('.search-form-wrap').addClass('visible', function() {
            $('.search-form').blindLeftToggle('slow'); 
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.search-form').blindLeftToggle('slow', function() {
            $('.search-form-wrap').removeClass('visible'); 
        });
    }
});
});
```

This seems to work based on the code from Blazemonger, with the addition of `$('.search-form-wrap').hide();`

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.search-form-wrap').hide();
$('.search-btn').click(function() {
    if ($('.search-form-wrap').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.search-btn').toggleClass('active'); 
        $('.search-form-wrap').show();
        $('.search-form').blindLeftToggle('slow'); 
    } else {
        $('.search-form').blindLeftToggle('slow', function() {
            $('.search-form-wrap').hide();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're testing if it `.hasClass('hidden')`. If you're adding/removing the `visible` class, you want to test if it's `.not('.visible')` instead.

**UPDATE**

If, however, you meant you want to test if the element is hidden or visible WITHOUT using classes, use the `:hidden` and `:visible` selectors instead of classes:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.search-btn').click(function() {
        if ($('.search-form-wrap').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.search-form-wrap').show();
            $('.search-form').blindLeftToggle('slow'); 
        } else {
            $('.search-form').blindLeftToggle('slow', function() {
                $('.search-form-wrap').hide();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: By changing if ($('.search-form-wrap').hasClass('hidden')) to if ($('.search-form-wrap').not(':visible')), it still works the same.

Comment: They're not the same thing! I suggested `.not('.visible')`, not `.not(':visible')`. One tests for a class, the other tests for visibility. Adding a class `hidden` or removing a class `visible` is completely different from testing if the element is `:visible` or `:hidden`.

Comment: I assumed it was :visible, my mistake

Comment: This works, accept once the animation is completed a `display: none` property is added to the search-form-wrap element.

Comment: Then go back to adding or removing classes. I'm no longer clear which approach you actually want to use.

Comment: I could care less on approach, im learning, so the best practices are what i'd like to use. The `search-form-wrap` needs to be hidden initially, then once the `search-btn` is clicked, `search-form-wrap` becomes visible, and animation applied to `search-form`. Once `search-btn` is clicked again, animation runs on `search-form`, and then `search-form-wrap` becomes `hidden`.

Comment: I got it working by adding a `$('.search-form-wrap').hide();` before the click function begins.